# 404 Not Found The requested URL /xxxxx was not found on this server

Tags: apache

Please i need help, I have gone through a couple of similar issues and how they were resolved and it seems mine is such a pain it just wont work.

I used a Turnkey Linux Appliance [OrangeHRM] and i want to use its Apache server to host another site/software [Sentrifugo] and it is so difficult, each time i host it only the default site shows up.

i have read through several similar issues here on stack overflow and it didn't work, i need someone to please take a look at my case.

Sincere appreciations in anticipation

---

Below is the output of `grep "<VirtualHost" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*`

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/adminer.conf:<VirtualHost *:12322>
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/orangehrm.conf:<VirtualHost *:80>
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/orangehrm.conf:<VirtualHost *:443>
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sentrifugo2.conf:<VirtualHost *>
```

Comment: Not a linux person o..

Comment: 1- What URL are you typing in your browser?  2- from that URL, you will know which VirtualHost is used (hint, port number!).  3- Assuming your VirtualHosts are in this order in your configuration, the sentrifugo2 will only be used when the port in your URL is **not** 12322,80,443.  Is that what you want?

Comment: 1- What URL are you typing in your browser? 10.0.0.18/sentrifugo2

Comment: 2- from that URL, you will know which VirtualHost is used (hint, port number!). no i dont know..if i got the question right, i am not sure i know

Comment: RE 1- So, you are requesting port 80 (default http port).  Therefore the VirtualHost that will match this is the orangehrm.conf.  Is that ok for you?

Comment: 3- Assuming your VirtualHosts are in this order in your configuration, the sentrifugo2 will only be used when the port in your URL is not 12322,80,443. Is that what you want? no, i want it to show up anytime i use the url http://10.0.0.18/sentrifugo2

Comment: hmmm...i didn't know that , how can i change this please

Comment: I mean to return the sentrofugo page anytime i use the url - 10.0.0.18/sentrifugo2 without specifying a port

Comment: I will post an answer, too short in comments.

Comment: I'd prefer to take out what ive done, if you can guide me step by step how to create a new virtual host

Comment: i just followed a tutorial while creating that vhost, so i may not know so much of what i did

Comment: Thank you...i will be waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning, based on what we discussed:

- you have 4 VH (VirtualHost): *:12322, *:443, *:80, *
- *:12322 is not a default port, it would have to be specified explicitly (http://SOMETHING:12322/...)
- *:443: default SSL port (https://SOMETHING/...)
- *:80: default http port (http://SOMETHING/...)
- *: matches all ports

Now you are using http://**IP**/sentrifugo2/...

- Using the IP address, Apache will check the VH in order and use the first one that matches.
- If you ask for http://**IP**/..., since this is port 80 (default for http), Apache will match the third VH (the *:80 one).
- But here you want the 4th one, the one with *

Solutions:

1. *Works, but is not the best*: define your 4th VirtualHost with a port.  `<VirtualHost *:80>`.  Then modify the order in which your VH appear in Apache and put the sentrifugo VH before the orangehrm.conf one.  But that *could* create a new problem where the orangehrm.conf is not usable anymore...  Keep reading...
2. *Best*: use name virtual hosting:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName orangehrm.conf
       ...OTHER CONFIGURATION DIRECTIVES...
   </VirtualHost>
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName sentrifugo
       ...OTHER CONFIGURATION DIRECTIVES...
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

So you see, this way, Apache can diffentiate between the two *:80, using the requested domain (or name).  On your client system, in /etc/hosts, define the two names:

```
10.0.0.18     orangehrm.conf
10.0.0.18     snetrifugo
```

So when you type http://orangehrm.conf **or** http://sentrifugo Apache will know which one you want.

**Note**: on Apache 2.4, this works no problem.  On Apache 2.2, you need to specify NameVirtualHost directive (see Apache documentation on this).

3. *Again works but not the best*: might not be possible for you.  You can split between the VH using a different IP address.  Ex. 10.0.0.18 is orangehrm.conf and `<VirtualHost 10.0.0.18:80>` is used.  Then 10.0.0.19 is sentrifugo, so `<VirtualHost 10.0.0.19:80>` is used (with Listen 10.0.0.19:80).  But you must be allowed to configure extra IP addresses on your host for this...
4. *another possibility*: split on the port.  `<VirtualHost *:80>` is for orangehrm.com, `<VirtualHost *:81>` is for sentrifugo.  For this, you need to specify `http://10.0.0.18:81/sentrifugo`.  This also requires `Listen *:80` and `Listen *:81`.

In conclusion Apache needs a way to know which one you want.  It can decide with: IP, Port, Name. Name is the most flexible.

IMHO using IP address is not the way to go.  It works in simple setups, but quickly limits you.  Use domain names.  Here I showed you how to do it in your local host file, the "best-best" way to do is to set them up in DNS.

Comment: + you can look up tutorials on Name Virtual Hosting, like this one: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 orangehrm
10.0.0.18 orangehrm
10.0.0.18 sentrifugo.ttl

Comment: That will not work as is, as you define orangehrm twice.  It will always use the first one (127.0.1.1).  And your VirtualHost directives use *, so it will match any IP address.  You can put the IP address in your VirtualHost directives ex: `<VirtualHost 10.0.0.18:80>`

Comment: FYI refer to this for NameVirtualHost: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations

Comment: First, i googled how to add a second IP to an interface, then i updated the  hosts file, i also included the ip addresses in the vhost definitions

Comment: Nice!  If you can approve the answer (check mark on the left) I would be grateful.